# Right shift operator used for checking number negativity

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am trying to check of a number is negative without using comparison operators. I am trying to examine the most significant bit. I am doing the following :

```
int x = -5;
Console.WriteLine(x >> 31);
```

I was expecting the output to be `1`. But I get `-1`. What explains this behavior?

Comment: This has to be a duplicate. Let me go find one.. edit: couldn't find a good dupe, actually. But the answers to this question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1499647

Comment: The right-shift operator shifts its first operand right by the number of bits specified by its second operand (MDSN).
It is touched about bits and I don't think I have the best explain for you but I believe this article can be very help you - [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx).

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because operator `>>` on an `int` behaves as an *arithmetic* shift: the bits that are "pushed in" take the value of the sign bit (either 0 or 1, 1 in your case). So the resulting number you get is `0xFFFFFFFF`, that is `-1`.

From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx):

> If the first operand is an int or long, the right-shift is an
>   arithmetic shift (high-order empty bits are set to the sign bit). If
>   the first operand is of type uint or ulong, the right-shift is a
>   logical shift (high-order bits are zero-filled).

If you do:

```
Console.WriteLine((uint)x >> 31);
```

This is a *logical* shift, the higher bits are filled with `0`, and the output is the one you expected: `1`.