# How to swap endianness of Int16 without BitConverter

Tags: c#, .net, binary, bit-manipulation, endianness

I need to read binary files containing millions of Int16 stored as big endian.

My first method was to use BitConverter and Array.Reverse() but that appears too slow for my purpose. Is there a way to do it with bitwise arithmetic instead ?

Comment: Jon Skeet created a [Miscellaneous Utility Library](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/). A couple of little treasures inside that library is `EndianBinaryReader`, `EndianBinaryWriter`, and `EndianBitConverter`. The reader and writer read and write binary data using the endian you specify. It should do what you need!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the math for an `Int16` would just be:

```
public Int16 SwitchEndianness(Int16 i)
{
    return (Int16)((i << 8) + (i >> 8));
}
```

or if you have a 2-byte array:

```
public Int16 SwitchEndianness(byte[] a)
{
    //TODO: verify length
    return (Int16)((a[0] << 8) + a[1]);
}
```

but you'll have to try it and see if it's faster than reversing the array.

Comment: Indeed, I had a 2-byte array to use.

Answer (score 1):

First solution proposed by Stanley fails when the `Int16` value is negative.
See [shifting the sign bit in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499647/shifting-the-sign-bit-in-net) for an explanation.

The proper implementation should be

```cs
private Int16 SwitchEndianness(Int16 i)
{
    return (Int16)((i << 8) + ((UInt16)i >> 8));
}
```